# residency visa expired in spain, I want to go to another Schengen area

Tags: visas, schengen, spain, overstaying, passport-stamps

My residency visa expired in Spain 8 months ago. I'm still in Spain and want to travel to Portugal. My passport was stolen so I renewed it. So I have a blank passport, no stamps of arrival. Will I have a problem traveling from one Schengen area to another with a blank passport?

Comment: So you are illegally in Spain ?? What happens if you are caught, most probably deported because you don't have a corresponding visa for your stay. Do you want to risk deportation ?

Comment: What is your mode of transport? If you drive there's no border control. You're likely to get caught in an airport / not being allowed to fly by airport staff without a visa.

Comment: Presumably you reported your stolen passport to the Spanish police, who will have a record of it including presumably your date of entry and visa expiry?

Answer (score 6):

> My residency visa expired in Spain 8 months ago.

Then you are illegaly in the Schengen Area, so will have problems in both Spain and Portugal.

> So I have a blank passport, no stamps of arrival.

The same as above, only it is more likely that it will be noticed.

> Will I have a problem traveling from one Schengen area to another with a blank passport?

You will have problems if you are **checked anywhere** inside the Schengen Area with a blank passport (i.e. no entry stamp or valid residence permit).

---

When a passport is lost, you must report it to the police.

Where possible, an alternative proof of entry (flight ticket, residence permit) should be supplied.

A resident must, after a new passport has been issued, register that passport to the authority that issued the residence permit.

A visitor should retain the police report and any other proof that they may have until they leave the Schengen Area.

The burdon of proof that you are legally within the Schengen Area lies with the traveler or resident.